# How to test QFN DFN components?

Tags: soldering, surface-mount, prototyping

I have found a smt component that I'd like to test.
It has all the terminals underneath the casing. For my test I'd like to connect it to a breadboard.
The dimensions of the components are shown below ([datasheet)](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/281/LXDC2HL_Series_datasheet_E-837146.pdf):

[image]

What is the approach to take to be able to attach these to the breadboard? Is it possible to avoid building custom stencils and PCBs just for testing the component?

Comment: You can solder wires - e.g. cut off resistor legs - to those pads, if you're careful.

Comment: You'll find some pretty good videos and explanations on the www when you search for 'dead bug soldering'. You'll need a steady hand, a good soldering iron and tip, and hot air soldering gun. I'd recpmmend solder paste. Also an illuminated magnifying and 'blutack' are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You could dead bug it.](http://willhb.com/2012/07/dead-bug-soldering-smd/)

This is a voltage regulator, so doesn't have any high frequency input or output that would be bugged by the stray inductances/capacitances that might arise.

Lay it on its back, and solder short pieces of wire to it.  Attach the input and output, and don't forget to connect the decoupling capacitors.

Make your measurements, then remove the junk and clean the pads with solder wick before you try to permanently attach it to a properly made PCB.

---

Exercise caution when working with your dead bug, else it may release its magic smoke.

Like this one did:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Get a small piece of phenolic pcb material and carve a "+" in it with a sharp knife. De-burr with a fine file. Solder the part with paste and hot air or wire solder and an iron.  Solder wires to the corners.

For more complicated parts if you expect to need to evaluate them before designing them in, keep breakouts for common footprints on hand.

With care to hand apply the right amount in a general area, and occasional cleanup you do not need a solder stencil for QFN ic's - if anything, it's more important for tiny passives, but only as a time saver.